# Save element jquery reference as a string

Tags: jquery, forms

I've got a function that accepts a reference to an element. This element will be used later (when a form ultimately gets submitted), so I'd like to save this element somewhere. I thought, since I've already got a form, I'll go ahead and save it as a string - stored in hidden field.

How would I do that?

```
$.saveElementAsHidden = function(elem) {
   $('#myhiddenfield').val(elem); // Doesn't work, just says "[Object object]"
}
```

Yes, yes .. I know you could probably save it as a variable, or as a `$().data` element in jQuery - but just entertain my curiosity here.

Comment: You can try with `JSON.stringify(elem);`.

Comment: @enenen and that returns `"{"length":1,"0":{"jQuery19008763641062468129":52},"context":{"jQuery19008763641062468129":1,"location":{}},"selector":"#dialog_canvasoptions"}`. Now what? How do I restore this reference when I intend to use it later?

Comment: You can try with `$.parseJSON(jsonString);`

Comment: There is no way to convert a reference to a DOM element as a string, and then get the reference back from that. The closest would be to use its ID - and if doesn't have one assign one to it.

Comment: @RoToRa sure looks like there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have the HTML of the element and use it. You can use `.html` on that element, store that into var post that info to server. When u need to reuse it, just make the HTML using that element HTML also and display it.